# Holding the zoom in the plot

Tags: matlab, plot, slider

I have 2 axes in my GUI in matlab, both are triggered when the slider is moved, 
and the plot is plotted in a loop(don't think it matters, just putting it out there).

```
tmp_xlim = get(handles.axes1, 'xlim');
       tmp_ylim = get(handles.axes1, 'ylim');
    for i = 1:length(sig)
            plot(handles.axes1,sig(i).time,sig(i).signal)
            hold (handles.axes1,'on')
        end
    hold(handles.axes1, 'off')

    for i = 1:length(sig)
            plot(handles.axes2,sig(i).time,sig(i).signal)
            hold (handles.axes2,'on')
        end
    hold(handles.axes2, 'off')
 set(handles.axes1, 'xlim', tmp_xlim);
          set(handles.axes1, 'ylim', tmp_ylim);
```

this code is inside the `slider1_Callback` so it's replotted whenever i change the slider, i want to the save the zoom so that whenever it's replotted it has to show the same part of the plot. I did try to use `xlim` and `ylim` but they doesn't seem to work and it's pretty complicated because i have to connect both plot such that when i zoom on one, the other should be zoomed in too. Because they're ideally same plots and i have linked axis too

Comment: I would use `xlim` and `ylim` anyway. Read the limits before plotting and apply it right after the loops. By the way, `slider1_CreateFcn` runs once. If you want to re-plot whenever the slider is updated put your code in `slider1_UpdateFcn`.

Comment: Sorry updated the code with xlim and ylim, which doesn't work. and my code is in slider1_Callback, sorry for that mistake

Comment: Please describe what happens when you run the code. Does it give you any error? Or the behavior is not as desired? Also, do you plot anywhere else before the Callback? For example in OpeningFcn?

Comment: The problem is,the plot doesn't appear.It's not like it hasn't plotted it. it just doesn't show in the axis as the xlim and ylim  has some value already, if i comment the xlim and ylim value, plot it and then uncomment it. then it works. Not sure what's the problem is. And no i don't get any error and i do not plot anywhere else than callback

Comment: Ok. Then that is the problem: You should plot it once at the beginning (maybe in the OpeningFcn) without modifying the limits. Afterwards, limit modification in the Callback should work fine.